# Is it true that if Y is a subset of a topological space X, and X,Y are compact then Y is closed in X?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to answer the following question:

Let X be a topological space. Prove or disprove the following:

If Y is a subspace of X and X, Y are both compact, then Y is closed in X.

I'm having trouble determining whether this is True or False. I know that Compact subsets of Hausdorff topological spaces are closed, and it seems to me that you need this notion of separation in order to ensure that every element in $X \setminus Y$ has an open neighbourhood which doesn't intersect $Y$.

The statement is definitely true in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric, since the compact sets are closed and bounded. So I'm looking for an example of a compact non-Hausdorff space, like {1,2,3,4,5} with the cofinite topology. But the compact subsets are all finite, and it's easy to see that the finite subsets are all closed.

I can't see how to proceed, is there an obvious example I'm missing? Or is the statement actually true?

Comment: Hint: Finite spaces are compact. So just have to find a finite non-discrete space!

Comment: @HeinrichD Ah, so X = {a,b} with the indiscrete topology. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ‘concrete’ example (I mean, not devised just for the counter-example):

Take a *discrete valuation ring* $V$, and $X=\operatorname{Spec} V$ (the set of prime ideals of $V$, endowed with the *Zariski* topology). Denote by $\pi$ a uniformizing parameter of $V$. We have
$$\operatorname{Spec} V=\{(0),\pi V\}.$$
$\operatorname{Spec} V$ is compact (as all ring spectra), and $Y=\{(0)\}$ is too. However it is not closed in $X$: actually, as in all integral domains,
$$\overline{\{(0)\}}=\operatorname{Spec} V.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be any set with the cofinite topology. If $A \subseteq X$ ,$A$ in the subspace topology also has the cofinite topology.

Any space with the cofinite topology is compact.

The only non-trivial closed sets are the finite ones.

So take $X =\mathbb{N}$, $Y = \{2n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. $Y$ and $X$ are compact but $Y$ is not closed in $X$.